# Android - Schedule Notification up to a year in the future

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

As per title I need to schedule a Notification up to a year in the future.

E.g. Today is **28 Feb 2019** and I want to schedule a notification to appear on **28 Feb 2020**

I tried going with `FirebaseJob` but I encountered the following problem:

```
val notificationJob = dispatcher?.newJobBuilder()
                ?.setService(NotificationService::class.java)
                ?.setRecurring(false)
                ?.setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                ?.setTrigger(
                    Trigger.executionWindow( Int, Int)
                )
```

The problem is that `Trigger.executionWindow()` takes two `Int`, that are 32-Bit values which is equal to about 24 days at most. While I need it to be potentially a whole year.

Is there another way I can achieve that?

Comment: I think you should use AlarmManager to schedule your notification. its the best way to set and cancel your reminder(in your case i.e., notification) as per your requirements. Learn AlarmManager from official site : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: The problem with alarmmanager is that is heavily influenced by doze as far as I know, so you're not guaranteed that the notification will be actually displayed

Comment: Its guranteed if you make the proper use of the Flags in alarmManager. Also, I advice you that, first you must implement it and then you can conclude assumptions on what it can do or not? use setAlarmClock() mehod it will wake your AlarmManager even in the dose mode. that's it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager for instance:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
```

For more information, you can check out the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager).